# Как правильно поставить в словах ударение и подчеркнуть безударную гласную?

Tags: орфоэпия

Мы живём в России. Москва — столица нашей Родины. Наша малая Родина — город Краснотурьинск.

Comment: По правилам форума Вам следует дать свою версию ответа, и, если в нём окажутся неточности, участники напишут о них.

Comment: Анастасия, уточните вопрос. Мне непонятно, Вы спрашиваете о технической проблеме - о знаке ударения и подчёркивании букв?